# Is there a way to produce an alert when an IIS site goes down using Prometheus?

Tags: iis, prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I have a few IIS sites I would like to monitor using Prometheus. Specifically monitor and alert on outages. I cannot figure out how to grab a metric when a site experiences an outage. Ideally, I would like when a site goes down to be able to provide that information, scrape the metric to Prometheus and then using the Prometheus Alertsmanager send it to our Slack webhook. I know there are tools specifically for this such as Pingdom, Uptime Robot, StatusCake but if I could do this using Prometheus, a tool we are already using, that would be better.

I am currently running WMI Exporter to get metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're interested in **blackbox-exporter** (see https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) to monitor targets via HTTP requests.

Once you've installed the exporter and configured targets, you'll be interested in alerting on the `probe_success` metric.

Comment: I think that will work! Do you know if you can use the `probe_http_status_code` in conjunction to `probe success`?

Comment: Well, you could simply alert on `probe_http_status_code != 200` , and use the special `{{ $value }}` variable to include the HTTP response code in your alert descriptions or summaries. I guess it depends on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using windows_exporter only. You should add W3SVC as the service to monitor. Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: IIS in windows can be monitored with windows exporter. Display name for this is W3SVC, which you can add in the queries. you can use process related metrics for this.